# Target all direct children of an element in scss?

Tags: css, sass

I have this css but I'm not sure what it means.

```
.container {
  & * > .content {
   color: red;
  }
```

I know if I have this

```
.container {
  &.content {
   color: red;
  }
```

It will affect elements with `class='container content'`

I also know, that `*` targets all elements and `>` targets direct childs.

So, this means that `color: red` will apply to all `.content` that are direct children of `.container`?

Answer (score 1):

`& * > .content` this will select all elements with `.content` class which are direct children of any element which are children of `.container`

for your case use this selector: `& > .content`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> .container {
>    & * > .content {
> ```

Compiles to:

```
.container * > .content
```

Or:

Any element that is a member of the class `content` and which is a child of any element which is a descendant of an element of the class `container`.

In other words: Any `.content` descendant of `.container` that is **not** a child of `.container`.

```css
.container *>.content {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    No match because the * doesn't match an element between .container and .content
    <div class="content">
      Match because the * <strong>does</strong> match an element between .container and .content
    </div>
    <div>
      No match because this is not a .content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

"direct children" is not a term used in CSS. There are children and there are descendants. There is no such thing as an indirect child.